# Use of spread operator in useEffect in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have to render a list of 200 celebrities from an API.
I already rendered once a list of 20 celebrities so I updated the useEffect like below to get 200 instead of 20

However, nothing is rendered when I don't use the spread operator, it only renders when I use them and I don't understand why I have to use 2 copies of my celebrities variable and the res.data.results with spread operator to make it work

Could someone explain this to me ?

NB : res.data.results is an an array of objects that I call to display the list of celebrities with all the properties associated to it (name, picture, famous movies etc..)
Thank you very much !

```js
const Celebrities = () => {
    const [celebrities, setCelebrities] = useState([])
    const [selectedCelebId, setSelectedCelebId] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        for (let page = 1; page <= 10; page++) {
            axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/popular?page=${page}&api_key=MY_API_KEY`)
                .then(res => {
                    setCelebrities(celebs => [
                        ...celebs,
                        ...res.data.results
                        
                    ])
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
    }, [])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, @OmenIII, as we do not have access to the API, can you elaborate on what is `res.data.results`?

Comment: Hi, @mgarcia ! Sure, thanks for the comment I will update my request, this is the object that I cann to display the list of celebrities with all the properties associated to it (name, picture, famous movies etc..)

Comment: It looks like you're making multiple `axios.get` requests, so you're best approach would be to use `Promise.all` to do all your requests, wait for them to finish, then update your state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are launching multiple asynchronous calls at the same time. I do not know if that's what you want to do, but take into account that they can resolve in different order that you call them (i.e. the request for page 3 could finish before the request for page 1).

Now, with the spread operator question. You are updating the state by calling `setCelebrities` with the callback form. Your state `celebrities` is an array, so you want to update with an array.

```
setCelebrities(celebs => [
    ...celebs,
    ...res.data.results
])
```

With this code you are creating a new array where the first part are the elements you already had (that's why you need to use the spread operator, so the elements you had are destructured) and the results you get from the API (which is also an array, so you need to destructure). If you don't desctructure them you will end up with an array of arrays.

If you don't want to use the spread operator, you can use the [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method:

```
setCelebrities(celebs => celebs.concat(res.data.results));
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what your saying, you can not understand the spread operator usage.
By doing this

```
setCelebrities(celebs => [ ...celebs, ...res.data.results ])
```

you are saying :

- take my previous celebrities (celebs)
- and return a new array [] that contains my previous celebrities objects (...celebs) and my new celebrities objects (..res.data.results) and this array will be set as the new value of celebrities variable.

If you don't do it like this, you will end up with an array that contains two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're making 10 different requests, you need to combine and not replace the current result with the previous ones, hence the use of spread or concat.

However, you've got 2 problems:

1. You're setting the state (`setCelebrities`) multiple times. Although some of this calls would be batched, others might cause unnecessary partial renders.
2. Since you making 10 parallel calls, some of them might finish out of order, which will cause the list of celebrities to be out of order.

I would suggest gathering the promises in an array, and then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all requests to resolve, and then take the array of results, flatten it with `Array.flat()`, and set the state.

Example (not tested):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const promises = []

  for (let page = 1; page <= 10; page++) {
    const promise = axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/popular?page=${page}&api_key=MY_API_KEY`)
    .then(res => res.data.results) // create a promise that will hold the results

    promises.push(promise) // push the promise to the array of promises
  }

  Promise.all(promises) // wait for promises to resolve, and get an array of results
    .then(results => setCelebrities(results.flat())) // flat the array and set the state
}, [])
```